# JQuery Rewrite HTML to Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a 'preview' written in JQuery, which when I write in a textarea, it is written in HTML so that I can see what the output will look like before submitting a post.

One problem though, is that while the main behaviour I want is for the preview to be written in HTML (so that i can see images in real-time), I need to configure it so any text written in the textarea, within <'code'> tags, should be written as text, instead of HTML.

Can this be done?

Thanks in advance guys!

To give an example:

```
This is text, displayed as text. The following image is nice: <img src="" />
Below is the code to display this image:
<code><img src="" /></code>
```

Comment: Are you looking to have entities escaped (e.g. http://www.elliotswan.com/postable), or just have the code formatted appropriately?

Comment: So just replace `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;` like any normal program.

Comment: i'm not sure what it is in javascript, but in PHP it's 'htmlentities'? It translates HTML tags, e.g. < becomes &lt; I was thinking it would be something like: $('code').text(); but it doesn't work

Comment: @animuson i don't understand why i should do str_replace when JQuery allows you to write as html, or text, I simply need to change the text within a code tag from html to text.

Comment: @Cristian: http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2 - So what's confusing you? That's exactly what this function does, it replaces those characters.

Comment: getting to convert the HTML to TEXT within the <code> tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you create the preview, you could just run this to replace the HTML inside of the `code` tags with text, like this:

```
$("#preview code").each(function() { $(this).text($(this).html()); });
```

Comment: absolutely brilliant, exactly what I needed. THANKS SO MUCH

Comment: do you perhaps know why the new text doesnt display the '/' in tags that end in '/>? e.g. <img /> is displayed as <img>

Comment: It might depend on the browser, but in HTML, as opposed to XHTML, `<img>` isn't required to have a self-closing slash.

Comment: thanks for clarifying that, is there any way to say to always convert to XHTML?

Comment: I can't think of any way that would be particularly straightforward. Is the lack of the self-closing slash an issue for you?

Comment: In regards to PHP, by changing from htmlentities to htmlspecialchars, the missing slash has resolved my problem when the post is submitted. The preview however using JQuery misses the slash, it's not a massive problem but if it can be resolved then that would be great